# ggplot2 not showing line in geom_point's legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a scatter plot with regression line, while using size aesthetics for one of attribute.  I realized that the legend now have overlaid symbol for fitted line and I want to remove that, keeping only the legend for size.  How can I do that?

```
> library(ggplot2)
> ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, size=cyl)) + geom_point()
```

This much gives this picture, which is good:
[image: no smooth line]

Now having smooth line on top, and then this blue "line" is what i want to get rid of, or at least make all thin like the one in the plot is.

```
> ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, size=cyl)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth()
```

[image: with smooth line]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use legend=FALSE option

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, size=cyl)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(legend = FALSE)
```

Comment: You are welcome. I struggled with this problem for a while before I discovered this option :-)

Comment: Good answer. I thought it would make more sense to move the size=cyl parameter into geom_point: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(aes(size=cyl)) + stat_smooth(legend = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

The most recent documentation {ggplot2} version 2.2.1 uses `legend.show= NA`

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, size=cyl)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(show.legend = F)
```